# Java multithreading for the purpose of simulating data

Tags: java, multithreading, statistics, analytics, simulation

So I am currently creating a data analytics and predictive program, and for testing purposes, I am simulating large amounts of data (in the range of 10,000 - 1,000,000) "trials". The data is a simulated Match for a theoretical game. Each Match has rounds. The basic psudocode for the program is this:

```
main(){
    data = create(100000);
    saveToFile(data);
}

Data create(){
    Data returnData = new Data(playTestMatch());
}

Match playTestMatch(){


    List<Round> rounds = new List<Round>();

    while(!GameFinished){
        rounds.add(playTestRound());
    }

    Match returnMatch = new Match(rounds);
}


Round playTestRound(){
    //Do round stuff
}
```

Right now, I am wondering whether I can handle the simulation of these rounds over multiple threads to speed up the process. I am NOT familiar with the theory behind multithreading, so would someone please either help me accomplish this, OR explain to me why this won't work (won't speed up the process). Thanks!

Comment: Is your code [thread-safe](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076747/core-java/design-for-thread-safety.html)?

Comment: see java.util.concurrent Executors and ExecutorService

Comment: Use [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) to determine how much parallelizing you code can speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is thread-safe and you can split the task into discrete chunks that do not rely on each other then it is relatively easy. Make the class that does the work Callable and add the chunks of work to a List, and then use ExecutorService, like this:

```
ArrayList<Simulation> SL=new ArrayList<Simulation>();
for(int i=0; i<chunks; i++)
    SL.add(new Simulation(i));
ExecutorService executor=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nthreads);//how many threads
List<Future<Result>> results=null;
try {
     results = executor.invokeAll(SL);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
executor.shutdown();
for(Future<Result> result:results)
  result.print();
```

So, Simulation is callable and returns a Result, results is a List which gets filled when executor.invokeAll is called with the ArrayList of simulations. Once you've got your results you can print them or whatever. Probably best to set nthreads equal to the number of cores you available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Java multi-threading, this explanation might seem a little difficult to understand at first but I'll try and make it seem as simple as possible.

Basically I think generally whenever you have large datasets, running operations concurrently using multiple threads does significantly speed up the process as oppose to using a single threaded approach, but there are exceptions of course.

You need to think about three things:

1. Creating threads
2. Managing Threads
3. Communicating/sharing results computed by each thread with main thread

Creating Threads:
Threads can be created manually extending the Thread class or you can use Executors class. 
I would prefer the Executors class to create threads as it allows you to create a thread pool and does the thread management for you. That is it will allow you to re-use existing threads that are idle in the thread pool, thus reducing memory footprint of the application.
You also have to look at ExecutorService Interface as you will be using it to excite your tasks.

Managing threads:
Executors/Executors service does a great job of managing threads automatically, so if you use it you don't have to worry about thread management much.

Communication: This is the key part of the entire process. Here you have to consider in great detail about thread safety of your app.

I would recommend using two queues to do the job, a read queue to read data off and write queue to write data to.

But if you are using a simple arraylist make sure that you synchronize your code for thread safety by enclosing the arraylist in a synchronized block

```
synchronized(arrayList){
 // do stuff
```

}

Comment: So basically I went ahead and *tried* to do it by ear. As far as I can see, it doesn't crash and burn, and it increased the speed DRAMATICALLY. Here is my GitHub Repo link if you're interested. https://github.com/Schwaitz/CSGORoundAnalysis

Comment: Mind telling me why it didn't crash and burn despite not using a synchronized() block?

Comment: @kuuy The way you are accessing your "matches" arraylist is not ideal, and in a moderately loaded realtime system would cause a crash.

Comment: I'll give you a brief explanation as to why and why it didn't crash in your case. Static variables are stored in the PermGen section of Java heap. PermGen by default has very small size 32MB for client mode, 64MB for Server mode. When you are running a massively parallel application that stores a lot of data in memory, you can see you will quickly run out of space in this section, and the application would crash stating OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: In your case it did not crash may be because your data set was too small, so not really filling up the PermGen space or may be you have increased PermGen size : -XX:MaxPermSize=XXXM. In either case you will not notice a crash.

Comment: The other issue you mentioned regarding synchronization. Issues with synchronization(that is not putting the arraylist in a synchronized block) will result in incorrect/misplaced data. Also if you try to remove data from the arraylist will result in ConcurrentModificationException.